# CSS - SubMenu position

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems with my submenu, it works fine when it's alone, you can look at this demo:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/7fN8m/.  However when I try to add it to my eshop template I am having some problems, because if I scale the browser window or use a different browser it is displayed differently, far away from the main menu.

I believe the problem is in here:

```
#categories_block_left ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}


#categories_block_left ul li:hover ul{
    left:270px;
    top:0px;
    display:block;
    z-index:1;
}
```

But I don't know how to fix it. Can somebody help me?

A live preview can be found on: http://presta15.priemyselnytovar.sk/ (left menu)

The full code can be found on: http://pastebin.com/pMKHUtdQ

Answer (score 0):

The li that is the parent of the ul submenu need s to have position:relative so that the submenu position relative to the parent li. without that the submenu is going to position relative to the nearest ancestor that has a position property set.

Comment: Sorry my english is not best so you  mean that parent should be relative and child should be absolute?

Because if yea i wrote it like this:
`#categories_block_left ul li{
    background-color:black;
    border-bottom:solid 1px white;
    width:100%;
    height: 30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
}`
and it didnt help ::(